# Jmeter - Execute .bash script using OS Process Sampler on Windows os

Tags: jmeter

I want to execute .bash script using `OS Process Sampler` via Jmeter 5.5

My requirements are:

```
1 Navigate to the specific path: C:\app\docs\release

2 execute as: ./no_longer_duplicate.bash dwtikz895261 6565

3 dwtikz895261 should be fetched as variable
```

what I tried is:
[image]

What I get is:
[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Dmitri T, but I wasn't able to get my results using `OS Process Sampler` and bash script on Windows.

The only way that worked for me was using groovy sampler and `processBuilder`

Here could be found the solution that worked for me -> [Jmeter - Execute bash script using 'JSR223 Sampler' and groovy, and output the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477223/jmeter-execute-bash-script-using-jsr223-sampler-and-groovy-and-output-the-r)

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to run a Bash script you need to provide the bash to [Bash interpreter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Something like:

[image]

But you seem to have Windows as OS, shouldn't you use [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/) or [CMD](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/a-beginners-guide-to-the-windows-command-line/) instead? Or even consider [JSR223 Sampler with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy), in that case it would be cross-platform