# Jmeter - Execute .bash script on windows (using groovy), and output the result

Tags: jmeter

Based on this query: [Jmeter - Execute bash script using OS Process Sampler via Windows os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74458691/jmeter-execute-bash-script-using-os-process-sampler)

I was able to execute bash command on Windows using Os Process sampler.

Now I need to execute using JSR223 Sampler.

```
String playerToken = vars.get("playerToken");
String command = "C:/Windows/System32/bash.exe /c cd C:/app/docs/release/ && ./no_longer_duplicate.bash ${playerToken} 6565";
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    log.warn(output.toString());
```

But I am not getting any output from the execution.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although earlier I posted question using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` this never worked for me,

what worked is using a different method and the help of `processBuilder`

```
String playerToken = vars.get("playerToken");
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Program Files/Git/bin/bash.exe", "-c", "cd C:/app/docs/release/ && ./no_longer_duplicate.bash ${playerToken} 6565");

        try {

            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

            int exitVal = process.waitFor();
            if (exitVal == 0) {
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println(output);
                //log.warn(output.toString());
                SampleResult.setResponseData(output.toString(), 'UTF-8')
            } else {
                //abnormal...
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

With this code, I was able to execute .bash script on windows, using 'JSR223 Sampler' and groovy, and output the result.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want this output?

If you want to have it as response data - add the next line to the end of your script:

```
 SampleResult.setResponseData(output.toString(), 'UTF-8')
```

if you want to see it in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) - add the next line to the end of your script:

```
log.info(output.toString())
```

if you want to see it in [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) - add the next line to the end of your script:

```
println(output.toString())
```

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)